# Searching for Text in column and incrementing the value in the next cell by 1

Tags: excel, vba, search, runtime-error, increment

In column 'G' of my worksheet I have cells with the text 'Months Billed' - I have code which searches for this text and in the cell next to the text increments the value by 1.

I found the code on this site but for some reason I get a run-time error 13 - Type Mismatch after it has changed all of the values. EDIT - I did a step into, once the code has run through column G and changed all of the values, it loops back to the For Each statement and then I get the run-time error at the found.offset statement.

Here is my code:

```
Sub UpdateMonthsBilled()

Dim findRng As Range, _
    targetRng As Range, _
    findCell As Range, _
    found As Range
Dim firstFound As String, _
    columnName As String
Dim Month As Integer

Month = 1
columnName = "G"
Set findRng = Range("G5:H650")
For Each findCell In findRng
    Set targetRng = Range(columnName & "2", Range(columnName & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    With targetRng
        Set found = .Find(findCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            firstFound = found.Address
            Do
                found.Offset(0, 1).Value = found.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1

                Set found = .FindNext(found)
            Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> firstFound
        End If
    End With
Next findCell


End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have no idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to VBA, and ran it.

It seems that rows G1 through G4 are being incremented as well.

No errors, however.  This is Excel 2003.

Comment: I am running excel 2013. When I do a Step Into the code is running through column G and incrementing the cell in column H for all 15 occurrences of 'Months Billed'. Once it gets to the last occurrence the code goes back to the For Each statement and then I get the error once it hits the offset statement. Is there a way to change the code so that after it has made a change to the last occurrence of Months Billed it ends?